# Compiler error, using this as a variable name

Tags: java

I've been having issues creating an array in Java compiled using javac in `Cygwin`.

```
public class arr {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int this[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

It tosses me a int : is not a statement

```
int this: is not a statement  
__^
```

I've also tried int[] this as well.

I've also added these to my `cygwin/home/ .bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/"Program Files (x86)"/Java/jdk1.8.0_65  
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Why is your variable name `this`? That's not valid to begin with.

Comment: Just was quickly testing out / customizing my cygwin terminal, I was creating a program to sum(this) and I realised it wouldn't take my int [] this = {1,2,3,4,5}; as is. ahahahah I see. I've forgotten that this refers to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is one of [Java Keywords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) and is used to reference the `current object`, you can't use this word as variable, you should use any other word instead of this:

```
public class Arr {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Arr {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `this`

Instead do

```
int [] something = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: I've tried this, and still receive the same errors.

Comment: @Genesis . exactly this syntax, without "this" ?